# Existence of solution of linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to know whether there is some theorem that states that solutions to differential equations of the form $$\frac{d^n y}{dt^n}+\frac{d^{n-1} y}{dt^{n-1}}g_{n-1}(t)+...+\frac{d y}{dt}g_1(t) + y =g_o(t)$$ exist and if they are unique. The function $y$ is univariate and is assumed to have $n+p$ derivatives and the $g_i(t)$'s are also univariate and have $p$ derivatives, where $p$ is any natural number.

What I have found online are mostly theorems that deal with equations where only the first derivatives are involved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want the multivariate version of the [Existence and Uniqueness Theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy-Lipschitz_theorem) for differential equations.  Your equation can be put in the form
$$ Y' = F(Y,t)$$
where $Y(t) = (y(t), y'(t), \ldots, y^{(n-1)}(t))$ and
$$F(Y,t) = (Y_2, Y_3, \ldots, Y_n, -g_{n-1}(t) Y_{n} - \ldots - g_1(t) Y_2 - Y_1 + g_0(t))$$